# There are a few questions about the select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a few questions about the `select` statement.
First of all, I have normalized 15 tables for this `select` query.
The problem is invisible because there is not much data right now.
However, since I try to process many tables in one select query, it seems to cause problems later.
So I want to add a few more select statements to divide the tables to search, but I want to know how different it is from doing it at once.
Secondly, if I use join, I will use `outer join`. If I join multiple tables with outer join, I'm not sure how to use `left outer join` and `right outer join`.
The currently created select query refers to 8 tables and one join is linked.
That is, the remaining rest of the tables have obtained data in subqueries and the remaining eight tables are likely to use join.
I would appreciate it if you could let me know the direction of the multiple outer joins.
Let me briefly show you some of the current select queries.

```
select 
a.cal1,a.cal2,a.cal3,...,
(select b.cal1 from b
where a.cal4=b.cal2)
as "bcals",
(select c.cal1 from c
where a.cal5=c.cal2)
as "ccals",
....,
(select e.cal1 from e
where a.caln=e.cal2)
as "ecals",
(select sum(extract(year from age(f.endday,f.startday))
from f
where e.cal1=a.cal1)
as "fcals",
g.cal1,g.cal2,g.cal3,...,
(select h.cal1 from h
where g.cal4=h.cal2)
as "hcals"
from a left outer join g on a.cal1=g.cal5
where a.cal1=?;
```

Result:

```
a.cal1|a.cal2|a.cal3|...|hcals
var1  |var2  |var3  |...|varn
```

After this, I wonder how to join the rest of the tables.

To sum up

1. If there are many tables that need to be included in a select query statement, what is the difference between performance and performance when this complex query is divided into multiple select statements?
2. If we write inside a select statement, how should outer join be?
3. Is there a problem with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is correct, but it looks very complex. People will find it difficult to understand it. Using joins you can minimize the lines of code and also make it more readable.

```
SELECT 
  TBL1.AMOUNT T1,  
  TBL2.AMOUNT T2,  
  TBL3.AMOUNT T3
FROM TBL1
LEFT JOIN TBL2 ON TBL2.ID = TBL1.ID
LEFT JOIN TBL3 ON TBL3.ID = TBL1.ID
```

In the above code , there are three tables, and two joins. One can easily understand and debug/make changes. Please try this for your code.

Comment: That's how I found several values ​​in a select statement at once. And the main table based on the query is A. Can I do an ```outer join``` in the A direction?

Comment: Finally, A and other queries have a ```1: N``` relationship based on the query side.  Some are ```N: 1``` with A, but A is 1 in relation to the table you want to ```outer join```.  Here we want to get only one of the latest queries from one of the time values ​​in the other table.  However, there are times when B or C may not have a value, so it is not possible to query.  What should I do?